# How can i restrict only one instance of url (http://example.com) to be opened only once on client side?

Tags: java, javascript

How can i restrict only one instance of url (http://example.com) to be opened only once on client side ?

I have a link on my site clicking on which opens a new window. How can i restrict only one instance to be opened ?

Comment: You cannot control what client do from server side. Only way is to use some sort of session variables to keep track. But it is not a fool proof.

Comment: Do you have some code sample? With your question it's not 100% clear if you need this control on a browser or on the central side. And, what's the purpose of your need? Do you want to avoid a user to click a link more than once in Javascript or is it more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all what you want is not to open a new page every time the user clicks a link.
You could set a target from "_blank" to some framename, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="myframename">link</a>
```

In that case when user first time clicks the link a browser will open it in a new page with the framename attached to it.
The next time user clicks a link. The browser will check that framename is exist and not open a new one, just activate existing.